# How to always get a positive output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

This is my code:

```
import random
minimum=int(input("Enter minimum value: "))
maximum=int(input("Enter maximum value: "))
if minimum>maximum:
    temp=minimum
    minimum=maximum
    maximum=temp
howMany = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
sum=0
n=1
while n<=howMany:
    num=random.randrange(minimum,maximum)
    sum+=num
    n+=1
    print("Your random generated number is",num)
print("Python's random average between", minimum, "and", maximum, "is", sum/howMany)
avg=minimum+maximum/2
avgTwo=sum/howMany
difference=avgTwo-avg
print("The actual average of minimum and maximum is", avg)
print("The difference from the calculated average and from the actual average is", difference)
```

When I am calculating the difference, I need to always get a positive number. I tried flipping the variables being substracted but I received a negative number at random times.

Comment: what about returning the absolute value of your result? Does `abs(x)` helps you?

Comment: [`abs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs)

Comment: Tip: you can swap minimum and maximum directly using `minimum, maximum = maximum, minimum`

Comment: Your code also has a second, more subtle bug: to see it, enter a minimum and maximum one apart from each other; for example, "4" and "5", and generate a huge bunch of numbers. You almost certainly wanted `randrange(minimum,maximum+1)`

Comment: @DanielMartin That's why I prefer `random.randint()`. I'm still terrible at remembering function bounds, and `randint` does what I think it should! :)

Comment: You should not use `sum` as a variable name since it also a built in function.

Answer (score 6):

You can take the absoulte value of a difference to get the "distance" between two values:

```
>>> abs(2 - 5)
3
>>> abs(5 - 2)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply the value by `-1` if its negative so the end result is positive:

```
difference= avgTwo-avg if avgTwo-avg > 0 else (avgTwo-avg) * -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips on improving your code:

```
from random import randrange   #import only what need
mini = int(input("Enter minimum value: "))
maxi = int(input("Enter maximum value: "))
if mini > maxi:
    mini, maxi = maxi, mini   #you can swap two values like this

howMany = int(raw_input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))
total = 0  # don't use sum as variable name, it is built in function
for _ in range(howMany):  #you can use a for loop and not have increment a counter
    num = randrange(mini, maxi+1) #add 1 to maxi to get the range you want
    print("Your random generated number is ", num)
    total += num

print("Python's random average between", mini, "and", maxi, "is", total/howMany)
avg = (mini + maxi)/2  # use ()'s for proper operation order
avgTwo = total/howMany
difference = abs(avgTwo - avg)  #use absolute value to get magnitude
print("The actual average of minimum and maximum is", avg)
print("The difference from the calculated average and from the actual average is", difference)
```